# How can you turn a rapid pulser on and off?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

We have built a number of large rapid pulsers for Floor D of Fosco's server's community wiki.

D, obviously, is for disco.

[image]
*Disco seen from the deejay's point of view, with two jukeboxes. I just wish there were more than two records.*

The soft lightning is done by a number of extended rapid pulsers. Basically, I took the basic structure of a rapid pulser and extended it sideways with further torches and powder. It works.

[image]
*Close up of the underlying structure.*

The nice thing about this is that it can run indefinitely without any external input (originally, we were fiddling with carts). The bad thing about this is that it does even when unneeded, which causes light updates to lag elsewhere.

A solution would be to put a sensor at the deejay's spot. When the deejay (or an heavy object) is in place, it's disco time. Otherwise, the pulsers should stop.

(A nicer solution could be had if jukeboxes emitted power while they played songs. Alas...)

How can we stop the pulsers?

Comment: Those images are dark, I can't see much

Comment: @tzenes Unfortunately, that's a limit of redstone torches.

Comment: is disco a needed tag?

Comment: but photoshop doesn't have that limitation :) I can brighten up the images for you if you want.

Comment: @Oak feel free :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just connect a switch to one of the wires.  This will cause the wire to function as an [OR gate](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/images/c/cf/StandardLogicGates.png), so the clock *(or "pulser", as you call it)* will only oscillate when the switch is off.

**[Edit]** By request, here are some example pictures:

[image: 4-Clock with switch]
[image: 5-Clock with switch]

However, the switch placement is irrelevant: you could place the switch literally anywhere in the circuit.

Comment: Could you make a diagram of this?

Comment: That definitely works. I think if you have just a clock and connect the output to an AND gate it works with less resources (one input being the lever and the other the pulsar) however it causes more lag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this, I have tested it.

[image: Switch-activated pulser]

grey dot = switch

red dot = torch

yellow square = block

Comment: Nope :) The rapid pulser is pictured [here.](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/images/c/cf/StandardLogicGates.png)

Comment: @badp updated answer

Comment: That picture is for the 5-gate clock/pulser, not the rapid (4-gate) clock/pulser.  The idea for both is the same, however:  you are adding an AND gate somewhere on the circuit so it does not oscillate when the switch is off.  As I mentioned in my answer, it is even easier to add an OR gate - just add a single switch to anywhere in the circuit.  The circuit will then only function when the switch is off.